# How can I send a request to the leader of a Zookeeper cluster (Java)?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I have a Zookeeper ensemble - leader and workers. I want to send a task for the leader. How can I do it? Obviously, the leader's address is not static.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the idea is that only the cluster knows or cares who the leader is. Think about how your requirement could work but just sending a message to the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how should I send a message to the cluster... A cluster is many machines... I can connect Zookeeper from another service before any request and trying to figure out who is the leader, but it seems to be overkill

Comment: Zookeeper is a way to manage a cluster. Sometimes the cluster needs to elect a leader, for example to arbitrate cluster-singleton type operations, but which machine is the leader should not be known outside the cluster, and it can change at any time.

Comment: Is this a question regarding how to determine which member of the ensemble is elected as leader at a given time?

Comment: @ArvanitisChristos yes, it is. What is the correct way to do it